# Problems using import with reactjs and CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, babeljs, cdn

I'm trying to use reactjs with cdn as best as possible, so I tried to use the code with module type, the most important react imports work, only when I try to import another file of my custom component it prints error.

index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="./core/main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
import React from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@18';
import ReactDOM from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@18';
import InputWithLabel from './components/input.js';

const App = () => {
    return(
        <div>
      <InputWithLabel
        label="Name:"
        id="nameInput"
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
    );
};
  
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById('root'));
```

The error I get in the console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/components/input.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

However I have no intention of using npm, I want to do this test with basic javascript.
I tried a few things, failing miserably, and I couldn't find anything on the Internet that satisfied me. I thank you in advance for your help and humbly apologize if I have not been able to figure it out

Comment: As the error message states, it does not seem the `input.js` file is available at `http://127.0.0.1:5500/components/input.js` consider reworking the `import` path to where the `input.js` file is served from the server.

Comment: @Wongjn Unfortunately, I tried changing the path or putting the absolute path but it won't budge from that error

Comment: I would assume that changing the path should at least change the error, i.e. `from ./components/foo.js` should yield an error message that mentions `/components/foo.js`. If the error message is still mentioning `input.js`, then you may have several places that are importing the file – ensure that you change all references to the correct served location. Consider also clearing your browser cache and your server cache (if any).